# Applying base heights to raster is giving me different results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have applied the DEM's base heights to both the raster image, the raster DEM, and a vector file.  The DEM and vector file match up but the satellite image does not match up at all.  Any suggestions to what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Same exageration factor?

Comment: Cant seem to find that.  Closest I can say is its in the same data frame so it has to have the same vertical exaggeration there.  Is there somewhere else that can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

This

[image]

Happened because layer offset and factor to convert…units

[image]

Are different between image and DEM it draped over

Comment: My factor to convert unit is set to custom 1 on both and the constant elevation before I had raised it to 500 to make them sorta close.  When I move that to 0 it lies way below.

Comment: If z factor=1, landscape you are showing kinda sortof do not exist on Earth, unless your xy units are not comparable with z units. Is your dem unprojected? If so project it to metric

Comment: So I messed around with the numbers some more.  When I converted the DEM to feer to meters it seemed to lined up.  If I did it the other way it did not.  But it works now so that is great.  Thanks!